# Deserializing to object 'recursively' with json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Consider the following scenario:

```
var toSerialize = new Dictionary<string, object> {
  { "0", new[] { 1, 2 } } 
};
string serialized =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
// serialized == {"0":[1,2]}
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(serialized);
```

This deserializes into a `Dictionary<string, object>`, with for key "0" an array with 2 integers. Great!

Now let's try this:

```
var toSerialize = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "0", new Dictionary<string, object> { {  "0.0", new[] { 1, 2 } } } }
};
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
// serialized == {"0":{"0.0":[1,2]}}
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(serialized);
```

Now, `deserialized["0"]` is a JObject. Using a `JsonSerializerSettings` argument to DeserializeObject with `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All` solves this.

Now, in my actual scenario, there's another list around the dictionary object, and this is where further deserialization seems possible:

```
var toSerialize = new List<Dictionary<string, object>> { new Dictionary<string, object> {
  { "0", new Dictionary<string, object> { {  "0.0", new[] { 1, 2 } } } }
} };
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
// serialized == [{"0":{"0.0":[1,2]}}]
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Dictionary<string, object>>>(serialized, _jsonSettings);
```

Here, `deserialized[0]` is a `JObject`, which I cannot seem to convince json.net to deserialize further into another `Dictionary<string, object>`. Is this possible?

Comment: maybe try making a simple POCO class with your data structur to which you can deserialize in.. That way JSON.Net might be able to handle it better.. Just a thought ofcourse..

Comment: Hm, the solution in the possible duplicate works for this case. I simplified my actual case, where there's another list around the dictionary, and then the suggested solution does not seem to do the trick. I'll quickly update.

Comment: Are you wedded to `Dictionary<string, object>`? JObject/JToken are a perfectly adequate substitute. JObject even implements IDictionary<string, JToken>.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. Non-issue indeed, thanks.